# Pass list element by reference in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I am working with this data structure which I call an "associationList", which has the following format:

`<| key1->{value1, value2,...}, key2->{value1,value2,...},...|>`

I want to have the function `Add[assocList_,key_,value_]` add `key->{value}` to the associationList by reference. I have the following code:

```
Add[assoc_, key_, elt_] :=
  If[Head@assoc[key] === Missing,
   AppendTo[assoc, key -> {elt}],
   AppendTo[assoc[key], elt]];
SetAttributes[AddToAssocList, HoldFirst];
```

The Add function works for this example:

```
y=<||>;
Add[y,1,a];
(* y is <|1->{a}|> *)
Add[y,1,b];
(* y is <|1->{a,b}|> *)
```

But when I change the example to the following, I get an error:

```
y={<||>};
Add[y[[1]],1,a];
(* y is <|1->{a}|> *)
Add[y[[1]],1,b];
(* Error - Association - "<|1->{a}|> in the part assignment is not a symbol" *)
```

Using any type of Hold doesn't seem to help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to change `assoc[key]` in Add to `assoc[[ Key[key] ]]`. This works because `assoc[key]` gives an association, while `assoc[[ Key[key] ]]` gives a reference to the association.

Comment: Interesting problem & solution. A lot of trial & error to figure that out I imagine.